# MySQL insert into not working for me with email

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is my code

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `cloudgaming`.`user_info` (`user_name`, `user_password`, `user_email`) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')";
    $registerquery = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if($registerquery)  
    {  
        echo "<h1>Success</h1>";  
        echo "<p>Your account was successfully created. Please <a href=\"login.php\">click here to login</a>.</p>";  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";  
        echo "<p>Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.</p>";      
    }
```

i've already tried printing the values, and they return as follows:

```
$username = testuser
$password = TestPass123
$email = test@website.com
```

but the query fails everytime
it worked before i added the email

any ideas?

EDIT:
I found the solution to this problem

I had reset the auto_increment to 0, even though there was already an entry with 0, i changed it to 1 and everything works fine now

rookie mistake

thanks to everyone who tried to help me :)

Comment: What error do you get? What does the final query look like after the variables are interpolated?

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: You should switch to a prepared statement.

Comment: And, did you create the `user_email` column? Has the variable been assigned? and... and... and...

Comment: @AlirezaFallah To avoid potential sql injection problems and avoid the need to quote and escape the strings.

Comment: I have created the user_email column, as well as the other two columns.

Comment: Add this before your code and see what message you get: `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: Then show us your DB schema. @DanielHolst

Comment: The final query looks like this after interpolation
    INSERT INTO `cloudgaming`.`user_info` (`user_name`, `user_password`, `user_email`) VALUES ('testuser', '058265891d5969fa23b7b007811e0cae', 'example@website.com')

Comment: @DanielHolst please post the error message you get from the mysql server. It tells everything you/we need to know

Comment: The error is    Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: did you put the key column to auto_increment?

Comment: yes it has auto increment

Comment: @DanielHolst: If auto increment was defined you would have not received this error. It seems you posted a wrong query without pk included in it.

Comment: Solution found. edited OP

Comment: maybe you messed with your data, try to truncate the table and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem.

I had reset the `auto_increment` to `0`, even though there was already an entry with `0`

I changed it to `1` and everything works fine now.

rookie mistake

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

i think the error is with the SQL statement. try this..

Sorry i am unable to comment.Therefore i have edited the answer.

i will assume that you have a field called id.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_info (`id`, `user_name`, `user_password`, `user_email`) VALUES ('" ", ".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."')";
```

Comment: Wouldn't make a difference, since the variables are already encased within double quotes.

Comment: You really should check the comments underneath your question (if you haven't already done so). @DanielHolst - No sense in people putting in answers if they don't know what they're dealing with, outside of what they can't see. ;-)

Comment: @Daniel, Please post the error message you get from the mysql server

Answer (score -1):

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `cloudgaming`.`user_info` (`user_name`, `user_password`, `user_email`) VALUES (' . $username . ',' . $password . ',' . $email . ')";
```

not

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `cloudgaming`.`user_info` (`user_name`, `user_password`, `user_email`) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')";
```

remove the "'" for variables,  VALUES (' . $username . ',' . $password . ',' . $email . ')";

Comment: Works for me? . $variable . rather than "$variable"

Comment: No, string values should be quoted although the correct way would be to use a prepared statement with bound variables.

Comment: I did `NOT` downvote but this `' . $username . '` should be `'" . $username . "'` if anything. The way the OP has it now, should work. I think the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: That's not for the variable, that's for MySQL. The query should contain quoted strings.

Comment: @Night You are just making things worse, now you are introducing spaces and dots in the inserted values. If the query would actually work, that is...